# Reusing a panel to store values

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, reusability

I need to reuse the textfield in the panel to store values.

Refer to the long but very simple code.

Basically what I am doing is

1. Creating a panel containing the textfield
2. Creating an array of object of class Holder that has variable name that is going to store values from the textfield

---

```
class Holder
{
    String name;
}


public class Yummy12 extends Holder {
    int t;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Yummy12();
    }

    Holder[] obj=new Holder[5];

    JButton button1=new JButton("add another one");
    JButton button2=new JButton("exit");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JTextField textfield=new JTextField("Enter some text here");
    JLabel label1=new JLabel();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();

    Yummy12()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            obj[i]=new Holder();
        }

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        label1.setBounds (165, 75, 100, 25);
        textfield.setBounds (350, 75, 100, 25);
        button1.setBounds (170, 230, 100, 25);
        button2.setBounds (360, 230, 100, 25);

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(textfield);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        ListenForButton1 lrbutton1=new ListenForButton1();
        ListenForButton1 lrbutton2=new ListenForButton1();

        button1.addActionListener((ActionListener)lrbutton1);
        button2.addActionListener((ActionListener)lrbutton2);
    }        

    private class ListenForButton1 implements ActionListener
    {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==button1)
            {
                obj[t].name=textfield.getText();
                t++;

                //what code should come here so that i reuse the same panel again??? 

                if(e.getSource()==button2)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: //what code should come here so that i reuse the same panel again??? what do you mean ?

Comment: simple Sanjeev, i use the panel with the textfield to store value into obj.name , now when i click button add another one then i need the frame to be displayed freshly so that i can store new values as i type into the textfield. hope it clears now!!!

Comment: @Creative_Cimmons If you just want to clear the text in the `JTextField`, you can use `textfield.setText("");`.

Comment: ok, that is not so optimal solution @Florent Bayle, this is just a scaled down version , i necessarily need to reuse the panel

Comment: You can use your variable named panel to do whatever you want to do with panel.

Comment: hello @Mo.Ashfaq yes i tried panel.revalidate and panel.repaint,, I even tried adding the panel to the frame again but doesn't work. What I basically want is the entire panel to refresh and come back

Comment: Refersh means clearing all the textfields or something else?

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq, yup refresh means clearing the textfields, in addition to that i could has JLsts, JSliders, and refresh for them would be to set to their default values. I know I could reset them individually but is there some method to refresh the entire panel as a whole. Thanks

Comment: @Creative_Cimmons according to my knowledge, there is no method to that. Because everyones referesh definition is different.

Comment: oh ok, thanx for Responding @Mo.Ashfaq.thank u very much

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

Your if block needs to be modified like this in order to make it work:

```
        if(e.getSource()==button1) {
            obj[t].name=textfield.getText();
            t++;

            //what code should come here so that i reuse the same panel again??? 
            textfield.setText(""); // clears the textfield for re-use

        } else if(e.getSource()==button2){
                System.exit(0);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: that is  a solution but imagine my panel having multiple text boxes, listboxes and some sliders (my actual implementation) then what would you do ?? thanx for responding @Sanjeev

Comment: in that case the same solution needs to be scaled up i.e. you need to save the values and clear all the textfields, clear the selection from listboxes and reset the sliders position.